# iOS Application is lauching again once it is closed

Tags: ios, ios4, uiapplication

In IOS 4 if the application is closed by user manually then it is not launching again it crashes when launched and i cant do anything.
I am testing it on Ipod4
When i pressed the hard key of ipad twice and close the app manually then i am not able to start the application again.

how to terminate the application completely do i need to write something in 
`- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` 
of appdelegate?

Comment: When you say 'closed manually', do you mean that the user double-taps the Home button, and then closes your App?  Otherwise, if the user just leaves the App by pressing the Home button, the App remains in the background, and 'applicationWillTerminate' is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have some serious issues with your code.
An application should support both going into the background and transitioning out of it into active state again, as well as terminating from the background once that is initiated by the OS, or by the user via the 'double home tap -> close' action.

Terminating the application forcibly through code is not supported and will actually result in apple rejecting your app when you submit it.